# Htaccess file edit subfolder redirect main page

Tags: html, .htaccess, web, dns, hosting

My code is under `http://domainname/senoglu`

But I want to see `www.domainname.com` but main page is `http://domainname/senoglu`
I don't have access top directory

I can do with htaccess file

But its coming 3 subdirector

Bodrum
istanbul
senoglu

Myweb page code is under senoglu/.
Istanbul subdomain like `istanbul.domainname.com`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainname.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/senoglu/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /senoglu/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainname.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ senoglu/index.html [L]
```

Tell me how it goes!